# Scraping Yahoo/Oath New Earnings Calendar Format

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

Can't figure out why the modified Python script below isn't working with the new earnings calendar format.  It does not appear to be matching the href which may be significantly different than the old format (dynamic javascript?).

```
import datetime
import requests
import bs4
import csv

def get_earning_data(date,date2):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?&day={}".format(date)
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"}
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    quotes = []
    for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
        if len(tr.contents) > 3:
            if len(tr.contents[1].contents) > 0:
                if tr.contents[1].contents[0].name == "a":
                    if tr.contents[1].contents[0]["href"].startswith("/quote/"):
                        if "." not in tr.contents[1].contents[0].text: 
                            quotes.append(tr.contents[1].contents[0].text)
                            quotes.append(date2)
    return quotes

outfile = "EarningsCalendar.csv"
open(outfile, 'wb').close
index = 0
while index < 7:
    date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(index)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    date2 = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(index)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    mylist = get_earning_data(date,date2)
    print (mylist)
    with open(outfile, 'ab') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for i in range(0, len(mylist), 2):
            writer.writerow(mylist[i:i+2])
    index += 1
```

Here's a sample page source row for 04-05-2017:

`<tr class="data-rowKMX9 Bgc($extraLightBlue):h H(36px) Bgc($altRowColor)" data-reactid="490"><td class="data-col0 Ta(start) Pend(15px) Pstart(6px) W(10%)" data-reactid="491"><a href="/quote/KMX?p=KMX" title="Carmax Inc" data-symbol="KMX" class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="492">KMX</a></td><td class="data-col1 Ta(start) Pend(10px) W(20%)" data-reactid="493">Carmax Inc</td><td class="data-col2 Ta(end) Pstart(15px) W(10%)" data-reactid="494">0.79</td><td class="data-col3 Ta(end) Pstart(15px) W(10%)" data-reactid="495">-</td><td class="data-col4 Ta(end) Pstart(15px) W(10%)" data-reactid="496"><span class="" data-reactid="497">-</span></td><td class="data-col5 Ta(end) Pend(6px) Pstart(15px) W(13%)" data-reactid="498"><span data-reactid="499">Before Market Open</span></td></tr>`

Here's a sample page showing the old format: http://web.archive.org/web/20170301070135/https://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/today.html

The only difference between old and new that I can see is the .startswith.  Using "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" does not work either.

Comment: `tr.contents[1].contents[0].name == "a"` is now False, because `tr.contents[1].contents[0].name` is only svg or None ...no links there...

Comment: Does this look like one of the tags you're looking for? `<a href="/quote/CAFD?p=CAFD" title="8Point3 Energy Partners LP" data-symbol="CAFD" class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="408">CAFD</a>`

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  "/quote/" doesn't match and I don't know if this is due to some kind of dynamic javascript issue where what the server sends is different than what the client interprets which I've read elsewhere can be an annoying problem with the new Yahoo/Oath layout.

Comment: What's the data in the csv file supposed to look like?

Comment: Each row is:TICKER,DATE

Comment: Seems like many things have changed, especially the datetime format, so I'm going to close this.

https://github.com/wenboyu2/yahoo-earnings-calendar